# Android Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a react native application. when I try to build the applications using `react-native run-android` the build fails. Here is the output of the error that occurs.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
253 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 248 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug
debug Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:607:13)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:627:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/FaisalHussain/mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:58:39)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/FaisalHussain/mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:142:41)
    at then.result (/Users/FaisalHussain/mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:104:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

The application was on a old version of react native (0.48.x) I have updated it to 0.59.10.

What I have done so far:

1. used jetifier to resolve issues with the plugins.
2. checked that the build tools version matches the compile sdk version
3. checked if the emulator is running.

Hence I have tried everything I could to resolve this but had no luck. Please do guide me on how to resolve this issue. Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have followed all the necessary steps from the upgrade helper https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.48.0&to=0.59.10

also i would suggest you to upgrade to v0.60+ because there are breaking changes after v0.59.10.

having said that

before you run the app make sure your gradle is clean 
run the following command to clean your gradle `cd android && ./gradle clean`
then later you can navigate back to your app folder `cd ..`  and try and run again `react-native run-android`

Comment: I followed rn-diff-purge in order to upgrade the application and believe me that this was not my first time updating the RN version to a new one but this app is giving me hell :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your packages not working stable with Android side. It's better be update all packages and react native version to their last stable versions.

If you face with too much error while update, you can create fresh new react native project (with same package name with your current project), install all packages (and their dependencies) and copy your current project's source code to your new project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have already thought about that but it does not seemed like a good idea because the previous developer has installed too many packages and for most there are edits in the native files but i think i would give it a try if nothing came out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Android in React Native does not allow similar packages to reside in the project.

In my case I had `react-native-cookies` and `@react-native-cookies/cookies` packages that add similar code to the Kotlin file upon build. This causes issue of similar imports in java JDK.

I removed one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was at /android/build.gradle file.
Somehow, the buildscript versions were wrong.

Follow the exact same step of RN documentation and make a totally new & clean project.
And compate the /android/build.gradle file > buildscript & dependencies part.
There should be some version differences.
It matters by your own local env settings.

After changing buildToolsVersion, ndkVersion, classpath, it worked fine again!!

Also, remove duplicated libraries, as [FAIZAN SAFDAR ALI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315863/android-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-react-nati/70075408#70075408) said.